# The usage of "utterly mysterious"

Tags: meaning-in-context, paragraphs, gre

> "Philosophy, unlike most other subjects, does not try to extend our
> knowledge by discovering new information about the world. Instead, it
> tries to deepen our understanding through *rumination on* what is
> already closest to us. Philosophy begins by finding ***utterly
> mysterious*** the things that are *most prosaic*."

---

---

This is the correct answer to a GRE problem that asks the candidates to fill in the missing pieces. I understood very well the *rumination on* and the *most prosaic*.

For the other one, I cannot comprehend what ***utterly mysterious*** means in this context. Since philosophy does not try to unearth new mysteries, but focusing and deepens understanding on what is already exist. Mystery is related to discovery. For this reason, I chose ***thoroughly commonplace*** rather than the other 2 options: ***essentially irrelevant*** and ***utterly mysterious*** as my answer. But the answer key says I am wrong.

Comment: Standardized tests often pair missing words as *same* or *opposites*. You needed to **contrast** prosaic with mystery, not more prosaic (common). Game such tests by going with your gut: "I'm not sure what abstruse means, but it's some negative thing like obtuse." Proasic is something like pedestrian or regular, and mystery is the opposite.

Comment: Compare statements about painters who must see the world through the eyes of a child before they can access their genius.  *Painters must begin by finding **utterly novel** what every adult takes for granted.*

Comment: Though Yosef 'answers' correctly, this question is not really suitable for ELU. It has to do with interpretation, and preferred writing styles. None of the answers violates a rule of grammar, and all are possible; if you were just given the single sentence, it would be harder to decide what the examiner wanted, though 'the things that are most prosaic' doesn't fit well with either _thoroughly commonplace_ or _essentially irrelevant_; a contrast makes the sentence better stylewise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I disagree with your assessment that this has to do with "preferred writing styles" and wonder why you don't find "the thoroughly commonplace"  and "most prosaic" synonymous. Cambridge defines **prosaic** as *ordinary and not especially interesting or unusual* and **commonplace** as *happening often or often seen or experienced and so not considered to be special". But I do believe this question might be better suited to ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what threw you off the scent is the use of the word **find** in this passage.

Compare:

> I find her poetry delightful.

A paraphrase would be "I consider her poetry  delightful" or "I regard her poetry to be delightful."

Both *consider* and *regard* involve *looking* at something, examining it, perceiving, apprehending, assessing, and comprehending it, its essence and its features.

So the passage is saying that the philosopher's job (the role of philosophy) is to look at the things of everyday life  ("the things that are most prosaic") but with an eye that looks more deeply into them, that is to say, at an angle that allows the philosopher to see beyond the banality and discover something vital, something worthy of attention and contemplation.

The philosopher must find the angle into the quotidien that reveals it to have hidden truths.

> Philosophy begins by finding **utterly mysterious** the things that are most prosaic.

The verbal complement "utterly mysterious" can come after the object:

> Philosophy begins by finding  the things that are most prosaic **utterly mysterious**.

Philosophy begins when the philosopher finds the banal mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

> Since philosophy does not try to unearth new mysteries, but [rather focuses] and deepens understanding on what [already exists.]

These two aren't mutually exclusive, which is the point of the passage. The text is saying that philosophy deepens our understanding of commonplace things by uncovering mysteries within them. Rather than gathering new information about the external world, philosophy finds (through "rumination") the puzzles within our *existing* understanding of it.